# Type declarations on REBOL objects

Tags: rebol

I know you can type declare arguments and returns on functions

```
    some-func: function [
   "some func"
    number [ integer! ] 
    ] [
    result [ integer! ]
    ] [
    help number
    return number
    ]

    some-func 1
    some-func "blah"

    NUMBER is an integer of value: 1
    ** Script error: some-func does not allow string! for its number argument
```

How about object properties though?

```
o: make object! [
    a [string!]
    b [integer!]
    c [o2]
    none
]

o2: make object! [
    c [string!]
]

an-object: make o [
    a: 3.141 
    b: "an integer"
    c: "blah"
]

help an-object

N-OBJECT is an object of value:
a               decimal!  3.141
b               string!   "an integer"
c               string!   "blah"
```

I've seen the type declaration on properties as examples, but is it just for documentation?

Answer (score 6):

This is a really good question, and something I've thought about for years. It turns out that Rebol's internal object storage mechanism can handle this, but there's no way of expressing it in source code. Why not you ask? Here's why:

Rebol currently has the concept of name-value pairs. That's how contexts and objects are expressed. However, it is often desirable for objects to include other information that's not just a name or value. The datatype is a good example. Other examples are comments attached to values, and protections/permissions on values (such as allowing read and write).

So, the problem becomes: how many various features do we want to support in the language syntax, and specifically how would we do that? It gets further complicated by the "optional" characteristic of these features. So, you can't really use positional semantics to describe the object. That means adding a syntactic method, which means adding keywords (because Rebol really tries to avoid punctuation.)

So, as a result, the source form would become fairly verbose, and I think we could question whether it would be worth the benefit we'd get from allowing the feature in the first place.

So, this is a case where the simple principle of Rebol takes precedence over feature creep.

All that said, if you've got an idea for a simple method of doing it, let it be known!

Answer (score 1):

It's just for documentation .. type checking is only done on functions.